# FORM looks empty according to DOM-inspector

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with an web app im working on. The input-fields in the form is added by jQuery. My form looks like this in the HTML-editor:

```
<form id="profile" method="post" action="Profile/UpdateProfile">
        <tr><td><b>Namn:</b></td><td><parameter name="Name" class="transform">@ViewBag.Name</parameter></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Address:</b></td><td><parameter name="Address" class="transform">@ViewBag.Address</parameter></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Postaddress:</b></td><td><parameter name="ZIP" class="transform">@ViewBag.ZIP</parameter></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Personnummer:</b></td><td><parameter name="Pnumber" class="transform">@ViewBag.Pnumber</parameter></td></tr>
    </form>
```

But it appears like this in the DOM-inspector:

```
<form id="profile" method="post" action="Profile/UpdateProfile"></form>
<tbody><tr><td><b>Namn:</b></td><td><parameter name="Name" class="transform">Anton Gildebrand</parameter></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Address:</b></td><td><parameter name="Address" class="transform"></parameter></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Postaddress:</b></td><td><parameter name="ZIP" class="transform">0</parameter></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Personnummer:</b></td><td><parameter name="Pnumber" class="transform"></parameter></td></tr>

</tbody>
```

It may look weird that i have no inputs, but when the user presses an edit-button, the "parameter"-tag transforms into textinputs using this javascript:

```
$('#' + id + ' .transform').each(function (index) {
         var val = $(this).html();
         $(this).html('');
         var tag = $(this).parent().html();
         var newTag = tag.replace('<parameter', '<input type="text" value="' + val + '"');
         newTag = newTag.replace('</parameter', '</input');
         $(this).parent().html(newTag);
     });
```

As you can see the "parameter"-tags isn't wrapped by the form in the DOM-inspector, and nothing is posted (i debugged using Fiddler) to the server. How do i solve it?

Comment: ?! You got `<tbody>, <tr> <td>` outside of a `<table>` it's an invalid markup!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the form around the entire table.

You can't put forms inside a table element but outside a table cell. The result you see if the browser trying to perform error recovery. It is usually a good idea to make use of [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (although you need to run it on the markup you intend to generate if you are generating it using JS).

(Also, [use css for layout](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=12&ix=nh&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+forms) and use [label elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label) instead of bold elements).

Comment: Thank you very much! That was new to me :)